# How to translate "constraint"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word "constraint" means something like "limitation" or "imposed limitation". I find it difficult in some cases to translate this concept into Eo. For instance:

- [Constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem)
- [Biological constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_constraints)
- [Constrained writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing)

Vikipedio gives *[limigo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limigo)* for the general concept of mathematical constraint. So "constraint satisfaction problem" could be translated as *problemo de verigo de limigo* or *problemo de limigverigo*.

In the same vein, *biologiaj limigoj* could be a good translation of "biological constraints".

To make clear that the limitation is imposed, I *elpensis* the word *trudlimigo*. A Google search gives only one hit, but this one is pertinent. Therefore, "constrained writing" could be rendered as *trudlimigita skribado*.

Do you agree with this elucubration, or have you other suggestions and examples?

Comment: BTW, FWIW: Constraint produces better art: https://blog.bufferapp.com/7-examples-of-how-creative-constraints-can-lead-to-amazing-work

Answer (score 3):

In addition to *limigo*, you could try *devigo* (obligation) or *retenilo* (something which can be used to hold something back).

I have mixed feelings on *trudlimigita*. It's not horrible, but it seems a little excessive. There's a danger in translating terms from our national language. First, we think that every category needs an exact translation. Second, we tend to translate literally, ignoring solutions which might be suggested by languages other than our native language.

I would probably say *limoj* for biological constraints, and *limigo* for constraint satisfaction problem.

The category of "constrained writing" seems awfully broad and is not a term I would use in English. In Esperanto I might say something like "verkado kun artefaritaj limigoj."

Comment: I agree with your comment on "trudlimigita skribado". One could also say "verkado kun libervolaj limigoj".

Comment: Also, "limigo" conveys the idea that the constraint has been imposed by some entity. It works with satisfaction problems; but "limo" is indeed better in a biological context.

Answer (score 1):

Mi kredas, ke en multaj kazoj la vorto *kondiĉo* peras la ĝustan signifon.

- Kondiĉplenuma problemo
- Kondiĉverkado

Pro la komentoj, mi aldonas la [signifon de "kondiĉ/o" lau PIV](http://vortaro.net/#kondi%C4%89o) sube. La dua signifo tre bone kaptas la esprimbezonon en

*constraint satisfaction problem* --> problemo plenumi kondiĉojn, t.e. devigan interkonsentitan aranĝon

ekz. donu al ĉiuj partoprenantoj tiom da papero, ke ĉiu ricevu la saman kvanton kaj ke restas cent folioj por la sekva renkonto.

*constraint writing* --> verkado respektanta devigan interkonsentitan aranĝon

---

*kondiĉ/o*

1 Cirkonstanco, fakto, de kiu dependas la efektiviĝo de io: unueco estas la ĉefa kondiĉo de nia sukceso; fari el io la unuan kondiĉon de ioZ; la kondiĉoj de bona regado; plenumi la kondiĉojn postulatajn por konkursi; la kondiĉoj (donitaĵoj) de problemo; necesa k sufiĉa kondiĉo; ĉe egalaj kondiĉoj.

2 **Deviga interkonsentita aranĝo, de kies respekto dependas la valideco de aranĝo, kontrakto**: diskuti la kondiĉojn de pactraktato, de domaĉeto; meti al io la kondiĉon, ke […]Z; sub la kondiĉo de alpago oni konsentis sendadi al ŝi tagmanĝojnZ; kun la samaj kondiĉoj, kun kiuj laboras ĉiuj ĉi tiuj sinjorinojZ; li ellernos nian lingvon kun la kondiĉo, ke ni elĵetu la vorton «kaj»Z. ☞ klaŭzo.

3 (ordinare: plurale) Ĉiu el la eksteraj cirkonstancoj, al kiuj persono aŭ objekto estas submetata, k de kiuj dependas lia aŭ ĝia stato: reguligo de la kondiĉoj de la vivoZ; batalado kontraŭ la premantaj kondiĉoj de la ekzistadoZ; samaj kondiĉoj, samaj superstiĉojZ; planto elmetita al favoraj kondiĉoj de temperaturo; la ekonomiaj kondiĉoj; esti en bonaj, mizeraj kondiĉoj, por efike labori."

Comment: This answer does not conform to the definition of "kondiĉa" in PIV, which is more like "agreed upon" or "conditional".

Comment: mi ne konsentas kaj kopiis la difinon de PIV por klarigi

Comment: Vi kopiis la difinon de "kondiĉo". Mi parolas pri la difino de "kondiĉa".

Comment: Mia respondo dekomence enhavis "kondiĉ*o*" en la unua frazo. Por verkado mi eble iom mise metis "kondiĉa" kaj nun korektis tion. Tamen "kondiĉa: Dependanta de kondiĉo (deviga interkonsentita aranĝo)" - vidu supre - do lau mi tamen ĝusta. Eble helpus, se vi mem citus ĉiam lauvorte la difinon, kiun vi celas.

Comment: I see you have edited out the word "kondiĉa" from your reply. I remain unconvinced - especially by "kondiĉverkado".

Answer (score -4):

You can use the word *obstaklo*.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. In any event, this would have been a better answer with more examples - especially from known dictionaries, or of other people using *obstaklo* in this way.